# Не прописывается Main-Class: Main в jar файл

Tags: jar, manifest

### Почему после сборки jar в нем (в jar) в манифесте не прописывается Main-Class: Main хотя в IDEA в Монифесте есть эта строка?

В IDEA написано так:
Manifest-Version: 1.0

### Main-Class: Main

в jar файле написано так:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: MySQL Connector/J
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.mysql.cj
Implementation-Version: 8.0.12
Built-By: pb2user
Specification-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Specification-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.mysql
Bundle-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Import-Package: javax.net.ssl;javax.crypto;resolution:=optional,javax.
 xml.parsers;javax.xml.stream;javax.xml.transform;javax.xml.transform.
 dom;javax.xml.transform.sax;javax.xml.transform.stax;javax.xml.transf
 orm.stream;org.w3c.dom;org.xml.sax;org.xml.sax.helpers;resolution:=op
 tional,javax.sql;javax.naming;javax.naming.spi;javax.transaction.xa;r
 esolution:=optional,javax.management;resolution:=optional,com.mchange
 .v2.c3p0;version="[0.9.1.2,1.0.0)";resolution:=optional,org.jboss.res
 ource.adapter.jdbc;org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor;resolution:
 =optional,org.slf4j;resolution:=optional,com.google.protobuf;javax.se
 curity.auth.callback;javax.security.sasl;resolution:=optional
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Export-Package: com.mysql.cj.jdbc;version="8.0.12";uses:="javax.manage
 ment,javax.naming,javax.naming.spi,javax.net.ssl,javax.sql,javax.tran
 saction.xa,javax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,jav
 ax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.transform.sax,javax.xml.transform.stax
 ,javax.xml.transform.stream,org.xml.sax",com.mysql.cj;version="8.0.12
 ",com.mysql.cj.protocol;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.protocol.result
 ;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.result;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.p
 rotocol.a;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.authentication;ver
 sion="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result;version="8.0.12",com.mys
 ql.cj.protocol.x;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf;version="8.
 0.12",com.mysql.cj.log;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.util;version="8.
 0.12",com.mysql.cj.jdbc.util;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.jdbc.excep
 tions;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.exceptions;version="8.0.12",com.m
 ysql.cj.jdbc.ha;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.jdbc.interceptors;versi
 on="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.jdbc.integration.c3p0;version="8.0.12";uses:
 ="com.mchange.v2.c3p0",com.mysql.cj.jdbc.integration.jboss;version="8
 .0.12";uses:="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc,org.jboss.resource.adap
 ter.jdbc.vendor",com.mysql.cj.configurations;version="8.0.12",com.mys
 ql.cj.conf;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.conf.url;version="8.0.12",co
 m.mysql.jdbc;version="8.0.12";uses:="com.mysql.cj.jdbc",com.mysql.cj.
 jdbc;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.jdbc.jmx;version="8.0.12",com.mysq
 l.cj.jdbc.result;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.xdevapi;version="8.0.1
 2";uses:="com.google.protobuf,javax.security.auth.callback,javax.secu
 rity.sasl",com.mysql.cj.admin;version="8.0.12",com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admi
 n;version="8.0.12"
Bundle-Version: 8.0.12
Bundle-Name: Oracle Corporation's JDBC and XDevAPI Driver for MySQL
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Created-By: 1.8.0_92-b14 (Oracle Corporation)
Specification-Version: 4.2
```

Почему мавен не хочет прописывать в jar Main-Class: Main ?
Как исправить?

Comment: Вы работаете в Oracle и пытаетесь добавить главный класс в JDBC-драйвер MySQL?

Comment: Я ещё не понимаю что такое Оракл. Я собрал код использую проект мавен сбилдил его в jar файл чтобы запускать приложение кликая на jar. Но он не запускается, я посмотрел во внутрь jar в манифест и там нету строки Main-Class: Main, я добавил вручную и джар запустился но при повторном изменении кода в ИДЕА строка Main-Class: Main внутри джара исчезает. Думаю нужно чтото делать в ИДЕА но что не знаю.

Comment: В приложении есть код соединения с базой данных.

Comment: В Манифесте в IDEA написано так Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main